# Adding a register in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got 3 tables as this:

Table_One:

[image: Table_One]

Table_Two (which is the "intermediate table":

[image: Table_Two]

And Table_Three:

[image: Table_Three]

The relation goes like this:

[image]

I don't know why the word `Total` isn't being shown as the result of the next query:

```
SELECT 

ID_Table_One, 
Select_Info,
Deb, 
Cre

FROM Table_Two

UNION

SELECT 

ID_Table_One, 
"Total", 
IIF(SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre) >= 0, SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre), "" ), 
IIF(SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre) <= 0, SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre), "" )

FROM Table_Two

GROUP BY ID_Table_One;
```

This is the result of query above:

[image: Query]

The field `Select_Info` is an "dropdown list" field, I mean, it shows already existing information with the next query:

```
 SELECT 
   [Table_Three].[Id_Table_Three],
   [Table_Three].[Id_Table_Three_Plus_Info] 
 FROM Table_Three;
```

I believe that the proper process to do this is by calling the ID 600 of Table_Three to be shown in the last `SELECT` of the query, that would be correct thing to do? If it's that, how can be done?

If I close Access with the same query I've got this result:

[image: Query2]

As you noticed, now shows the register `Total` but only "the number part" it's being shown, I'm missing the - A, - B and - C part. I've tried changing the order in the Id_Table_Three_Plus_Info field (A - 100) but it always shows the number, not the letter. Both of them are text values.

I can deal with this by creating a new field with all the values I need (100 - A, 200 - B ... 600 - TOTAL), I mean, by not taking those registers by a query for filling the `Select_Info` field. But I would like suggestions for this rare query behaviour.

Comment: Is the `Select_Info` field a lookup field displaying something else than stored in that field (in a combobox)?

Comment: Yes, It is a lookup field, with the next options: `100 - A, 200 - B, 300 - C` ... until `600 - TOTAL`, knowing that, is there any way to select the "option" or register `600 - TOTAL` as the value in the field `Select_Info`

Comment: For sure, there is a way. Please let us know the lookup settings (query?) and datatypes of the fileds used in that query.

Comment: The `Select_Info` contains a query that selects `Id_Table_Three` and `Id_Table_Three_Plus_Info` from `Table_Three`, the `Id_Table_Three_Plus_Info` is a calculated field wich is `[Id_Table_Three] & " - " & [Info]` both of them are text datatypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you have edited your question and have now added more details, I think that you just have to edit the second part of your UNION query and replace the value of "Total" by 600 as follows:

```
SELECT 

ID_Table_One, 
600, 
IIF(SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre) >= 0, SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre), "" ), 
IIF(SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre) <= 0, SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre), "" )

FROM Table_Two

GROUP BY ID_Table_One;
```

This will show the lookup value of "600 - Total" as desired.

Comment: Thank you, but showed only the number 600 and afected the same way the field `Select_Info` as it appears in the last table of my question

Comment: Please check the lookup settings in `Table_Two` (`Select_Info` field) and make sure that the "column count" is 2, the "bound column" is 1 and the "column widths" is 0 (this will hide the bound column and only display the descriptive text).

Comment: Yes, I checked that, the only thing I had to edit was the column widths to 0, but still the same result

Comment: Is the lookup query still the same that you posted in your updated question?

Comment: Yes:`SELECT 
Table_Three.Id_Table_Three, 
Table_Three.Id_Table_Three_Plus_Info 
FROM Table_Three;`

Comment: Well, something must have changed between *This is the result of query above* and the result after *If I close Access with the same query I've got this result* (where the `Deb` and `Cre` numbers suddenly are left-aligned). You could have for example used a query in the first place and a form in the second. If you insinst that nothing changed, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Right, I reviewed it and it finally worked! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to see that. Welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with an alias:

```
ID_Table_One, 
"Total" As Select_Info, 
IIF(SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre) >= 0, SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre), "" ), 
IIF(SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre) <= 0, SUM(Deb) - Sum(Cre), "" )
```

Comment: Thank you, I added that but still the same result

Comment: I can't tell. I can't replicate your issue - it works fine for me even with a lookup field. I would start from scratch using the simplest queries possible, then expand bit by bit until you meet the issue.

Comment: I think that if the key field is hidden and the list of keys doesn't contain `"Total"` (in the bound field of the combobox), there is no display text to be shown.